# AES128 CTR encryption with iv

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, commoncrypto

I want to implement AES128 CTR with iv and key. I'm looking for any advice how to do that in best way and not reinvent wheel.

I found good lib for this [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/), but looks like this aes is not supported there.

Also I test [this](https://gist.github.com/mythosil/1292807) approach, but looks like this is not CTR.

EDIT

---

I used zpproach from @zaph

```
NSData *result = [NSData cryptData:dataStr
                         operation:kCCEncrypt
                              mode:kCCModeCTR
                         algorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES128
                           padding:ccNoPadding
                         keyLength:kCCKeySizeAES128
                                iv:ivHex
                               key:keyHex
                             error:&error];
```

but receive `CCCryptorCreate status: -4305`

Just found in sources

`@constant   kCCUnimplemented    Function not implemented for the current algorithm.`

[Link](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h)

Comment: Is there some particular reason CTR mode is required? It is not easy to get there CTR correct and care must be taken that the same counter value is never used with the same key.

Comment: `kCCAlgorithmAES128` should be `kCCAlgorithmAES`

Comment: @zaph just test - result same =/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use CommonCrypto but not the one-shot `CCCrypt` version, but instead the full `CCCryptorCreateWithMode`, `CCCryptorUpdate`, `CCCryptorFinal` and  `CCCryptorRelease` with mode `kCCModeCTR` version.

Here is sample code I have, it may not fit your needs and you will have to decide on the counter (IV) form.

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

+ (NSData *)cryptData:(NSData *)dataIn
            operation:(CCOperation)operation  // kCC Encrypt, Decrypt
                 mode:(CCMode)mode            // kCCMode ECB, CBC, CFB, CTR, OFB, RC4, CFB8
            algorithm:(CCAlgorithm)algorithm  // CCAlgorithm AES DES, 3DES, CAST, RC4, RC2, Blowfish
              padding:(CCPadding)padding      // cc NoPadding, PKCS7Padding
            keyLength:(size_t)keyLength       // kCCKeySizeAES 128, 192, 256
                   iv:(NSData *)iv            // CBC, CFB, CFB8, OFB, CTR
                  key:(NSData *)key
                error:(NSError **)error
{
    if (key.length != keyLength) {
        NSLog(@"CCCryptorArgument key.length: %lu != keyLength: %zu", (unsigned long)key.length, keyLength);
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kArgumentError key length" code:key.length userInfo:nil];
        }
        return nil;
    }

    size_t dataOutMoved = 0;
    size_t dataOutMovedTotal = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus = 0;
    CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;

    ccStatus = CCCryptorCreateWithMode(operation, mode, algorithm,
                                       padding,
                                       iv.bytes, key.bytes,
                                       keyLength,
                                       NULL, 0, 0, // tweak XTS mode, numRounds
                                       kCCModeOptionCTR_BE, // CCModeOptions
                                       &cryptor);

    if (cryptor == 0 || ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"CCCryptorCreate status: %d", ccStatus);
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kCreateError" code:ccStatus userInfo:nil];
        }
        CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
        return nil;
    }

    size_t dataOutLength = CCCryptorGetOutputLength(cryptor, dataIn.length, true);
    NSMutableData *dataOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataOutLength];
    char *dataOutPointer = (char *)dataOut.mutableBytes;

    ccStatus = CCCryptorUpdate(cryptor,
                               dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length,
                               dataOutPointer, dataOutLength,
                               &dataOutMoved);
    dataOutMovedTotal += dataOutMoved;

    if (ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"CCCryptorUpdate status: %d", ccStatus);
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kUpdateError" code:ccStatus userInfo:nil];
        }
        CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
        return nil;
    }

    ccStatus = CCCryptorFinal(cryptor,
                              dataOutPointer + dataOutMoved, dataOutLength - dataOutMoved,
                              &dataOutMoved);
    if (ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"CCCryptorFinal status: %d", ccStatus);
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kFinalError" code:ccStatus userInfo:nil];
        }
        CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);
        return nil;
    }

    CCCryptorRelease(cryptor);

    dataOutMovedTotal += dataOutMoved;
    dataOut.length = dataOutMovedTotal;

    return dataOut;
}
```

Sample invocation:

```
NSData *dataIn  = [@"DataInDataInData" dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *key     = [@"KeyKeyKeyKeyKeyK" dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *counter = [@"CounterCounterCo" dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSData *encrpted = [Crypto
                    cryptData:dataIn
                    operation:kCCEncrypt
                    mode:kCCModeCTR
                    algorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES
                    padding:ccNoPadding
                    keyLength:kCCKeySizeAES128
                    iv:counter
                    key:key
                    error:&error];
NSLog(@"encrypted: %@", encrpted);
```

Output: `encrypted: 064e8073 76973eba 3192474f 9831db34`

Comment: Have you ever tried to implement encryption using CommonCrypto in separate framework (e.g. in cocoa pod)? I had an issue with importing non modular .h in pod’s umbrella file. Any thoughts on workaround?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with CocoaPods. You might check hoe RNCryptor accomplished this, see [cocoapods & RNCryptor](https://cocoapods.org/pods/RNCryptor)

Comment: @zaph I try to use your approach but got error `CCCryptorCreate status: -4305` (please see edit), can u advice?

Comment: CommonCrypto error codes from <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptoError.h>: kCCSuccess          = 0,
    kCCParamError       = -4300,
    kCCBufferTooSmall   = -4301,
    kCCMemoryFailure    = -4302,
    kCCAlignmentError   = -4303,
    kCCDecodeError      = -4304,
    kCCUnimplemented    = -4305,
    kCCOverflow         = -4306,
    kCCRNGFailure       = -4307,
    kCCUnspecifiedError = -4308,
    kCCCallSequenceError= -4309,
    kCCKeySizeError     = -4310,

Comment: Missing and needed for CTR mode is `CCModeOptions` `kCCModeOptionCTR_LE` or `kCCModeOptionCTR_BE`, added to the sample code. I had forgotten this for CTR mode. Yes they are deprecated but needed.

Comment: I will check this again and let you know

Comment: @zaph - i tested proposed variant - and all works as expected - choose this variant because it's much better that SwiftCrypto. BTW, do you know any good tutorial related to CommonCrypto usage?

Comment: Not really. For CBC & ECB modes there is a combined call. Most usage is CBC and PKCS#7 padding.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) library. It supports AES and CTR.

Another popular crypoto-library is libsodium, but I can't be sure it supports CTR.

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security such as timing and power attacks.